# DataGridView selected row to display in text boxes based on first row of filtered data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How can I display the first selected row values to text boxes after I filter the data in the datagridview?

```
private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgpay.DataSource = p.SearchInPaymentVouchers("PaymentVouchers.VendorID", comven.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```

Comment: So you have a DataGridView which displays N rows and onclicking any row you want those values displayed on labels? Some more info about the situationa and some more code would be greatly appreciated

Comment: No the first selected row from the filtered data

Comment: Please clarify!!! Once the filtration has been done datagridview has been got bind at that time you want values of first row get bind in textbox?

Comment: yes that what i meant

Comment: Can you please let me know the return type of "SearchInPaymentVouchers" function?

Comment: It returns Data-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = p.SearchInPaymentVouchers("PaymentVouchers.VendorID", comven.SelectedValue.ToString());
    dgpay.DataSource = dt;

    //Code to bind first row in textbox.
    //check if the datatable has rows
    if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        textbox.text = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["id"]);
        //Row[line index you want to get]["Header of datatable column ex VendorID"]
    }
}
```

Hope this is what you actually want. Please feel free to ask if you face any problem.